# jQuery get class that starts with

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML

```
<button class="c1 c2 user-1"></button>
<button class="c1 c2 user-2"></button>
<button class="c1 c2 user-3"></button>
```

I know which button was clicked, how do I get the `user-#` class from it?

Comment: @guradio that gets the element, not the class name

Comment: will the class be scrambled ? you can get the attr class split it using space then pop getting the last element which the class you want

Comment: use $('button').click(function(){ $(this).attr('class'); });

Answer (score 4):

One method would be to use a Regular expression to pull apart the `class` attribute value, something like this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var classes = $(this).attr('class');
  var userClass = classes.match(/user\-\d+/gi)[0];
  console.log(userClass);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="c1 c2 user-1"></button>
<button class="c1 c2 user-2"></button>
<button class="c1 c2 user-3"></button>
<button class="c1 c2 user-111 foo1"></button>
```

However a more extensible, flexible and reliable solution would be to store the `user-X` value in a `data` attribute on the element:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var user = $(this).data('user');
  console.log(user);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="c1 c2" data-user="user-1"></button>
<button class="c1 c2" data-user="user-2"></button>
<button class="c1 c2" data-user="user-3"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming class will be like that in OP

you can get the attr class split it using space then pop getting the last element which the class you want

```js
$("button").click(function() {

  var thisclass = $(this).attr("class")

  alert(thisclass.split(" ").pop())

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="c1 c2 user-1">1</button>
<button class="c1 c2 user-2">2</button>
<button class="c1 c2 user-3">3</button>
```

Comment: Just be aware that this would be easily broken if the OP adds another class to the element without remembering the JS is tied closely to the element.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `class` attribute which was clicked and use a regex like:

```
.replace(/.*(user-\d+).*/g,'$1')
```

to get the *user-#* out of it - see demo below:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('class').replace(/.*(user-\d+).*/g,'$1'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="c1 c2 user-1">one</button>
<button class="c1 c2 user-2">two</button>
<button class="c1 c2 user-3">three</button>
<button class="user-45 c1 c2">four</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```js
function getUser(list) {
  
  return list
    .reduce((res, classname) => {
      const re = /user-(\w+)$/;
      const user = re.exec(classname);
      if(user) {
        res.push(user[1]);
      }
      
      return res;
    }, [])
  ;
}

function onButtonsClick(event) {
  const classes = Array.from(event.target.classList);
  
  console.log(getUser(classes));
}

Array
  .prototype
  .forEach
  .call(document.querySelectorAll('button'), element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', onButtonsClick);
  })
;
```

```html
<button class="c1 c2 user-1">User 1</button>
<button class="c1 c2 user-2">User 2</button>
<button class="c1 c2 user-3">User 3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var allClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
  console.log(allClass[allClass.length - 1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="c1 c2 user-1"></button>
<button class="c1 c2 user-2"></button>
<button class="c1 c2 user-3"></button>
```

Get all the classs of the clicked button using `.attr('class');`.
Then split it on the basis of space and get the last element from array.

Hope this will help you.